# Matches exactly regular expression not work in dart

Tags: javascript, regex, dart

Java script regular expression

```
/\d(.*)\s[0-9A-Z:]{17}/i
```

Test Case

```js
console.log("11  salus_biura                      68:d7:9a:da:7d:6a   WPA2PSK/AES            29       11b/g/n NONE   In  NO    ".match(/\d(.*)\s[0-9A-Z:]{17}/i)[1]);
```

Dart code

```
void main() {
   String wifiInfo = "11  salus_biura                      68:d7:9a:da:7d:6a   WPA2PSK/AES            29       11b/g/n NONE   In  NO    ";
   Match? matches =   RegExp(r'\\d(.*)\\s[0-9A-Z:]{17}', caseSensitive: true).firstMatch(wifiInfo);
   print(matches?.group(1)); // null 
}
```

**issue {17} Matches exactly not work**

output in dart **1  salus_biura**

Comment: Your JS regex contains `/i` flag, but in Dart, you use `caseSensitive: true` - why? It should be `caseSensitive: false` Also, in `r'...'`, you need single backslashes

Comment: /i == caseSensitive: true in dar right?

Comment: No, see the answer below.

Comment: yes it's working thank you very much for quick support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Dart code,

- Use `caseSensitive: true` as you have an `i` flag (that enables case *in*sensitive matching) in your JavaScript regex
- Use single backslashes in a raw string literal. `"\\d"` = `r"\d"`.

The fix code can look like

```dart
void main() {
  String wifiInfo = "11  salus_biura                      68:d7:9a:da:7d:6a   WPA2PSK/AES            29       11b/g/n NONE   In  NO    ";
  Match? matches =   RegExp(r'\d(.*)\s[0-9A-Z:]{17}', caseSensitive: false).firstMatch(wifiInfo);
  print(matches?.group(1)); // => 1  salus_biura   
}
```